# Is there way to send different parameter values to different classes inside a test inside testng.xml

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I need to pass a different parameter value for different classes inside a test. The following code gives me an error saying :

> "The content of element type "classes" must match
>   '(class*,parameter*)'.".

Is there any other way I can pass the parameter value to be accessible by a class?

```xml
  <suite name="Project">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
      <classes>
      <parameter name="URL" value="https://testRunner1.com" />
      <class name="project.TestRunner1"/>
      <parameter name="URL" value="https://testRunner2.com" />
      <class name="project.TestRunner2"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions.
1. Move the classes to different test as given below. Here you can have same name for the Parameters.

```
<suite name="Project">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
      <classes>
      <parameter name="URL" value="https://testRunner1.com" />
      <class name="project.TestRunner1"/>          
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
      <parameter name="URL" value="https://testRunner2.com" />
      <class name="project.TestRunner2"/>
   </test>
</suite>
```

2. You need to change the parameter name in the class and change the xml as given below

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote my code like below which worked.

```
  <suite name="Project">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
      <classes>
         <class name="project.TestRunner1">
             <parameter name="URL" value="https://testRunner1.com" />
         </class>
         <class name="project.TestRunner2">
             <parameter name="URL" value="https://testRunner2.com" />
         </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```